# Help me translate $X = Y \iff (\forall x : \in X \Leftrightarrow x \in Y) $ to english

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X = Y \iff (\forall x : x\in X \Leftrightarrow x \in Y) $

My best try is: "The set X is equal to Y, which is equivalent to saying that for all x defined as an element of set X is the same as x being in Y"

It's supposed to say that two random sets are the same if they contain all the same elements.

Comment: "Two sets are eqaul **iff** they have the same elements."

Comment: "Two sets are equal if each is a subset of the other."

Comment: @Surb Does $\Leftrightarrow$ mean that the left side is only true if the right side is also true and does the $\forall x : $ bit apply to both?

Comment: Sure but my sentence is the english version of $X=Y$ if and only if $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$. Which is an equivalent definition of two sets being equal. The point is: if you want to translate exactly the statement in your question, then ignore my comment. If you want a plain english definition of equality between sets, then you may consider my comment.

Comment: @Surb What is the difference between than C symbol and the underlined one? I know one means that it's equal or a subset of the other set, something like that.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire depends on the author. Some people use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ in the exact same way. Some people use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ to make the difference between strict subset and subset or equal. Finally, some people use $\subsetneq$ and $\subseteq$ to distinguish strict and subset or equal. Personally, I think all are quite confusing. I prefer to use only $\subset$ and state that the sets are different if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The set $X$ is equal to the set $Y$ if and only if every element of $X$ is also an element of $Y$ and every element of $Y$ is also an element of $X$.

Comment: But that only says that X is in that case a subset of Y not necessarily equal...

Comment: How come? What I wrote is symmetrical with respect to $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Your "The set X is equal to Y, which is equivalent to saying that for all x defined as an element of set X is the same as x being in Y" is definitely wrong. Because it says that $X$ *is* equal to $Y$, which the given formula does not assert. The formula simply says that $X$ is equal to $Y$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ have the same elements.